# Options to copy multiple tables with one million rows from on-prem SQL 2012 to SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have around 20 tables in my On-prem SQL server 2012 that I like to copy them to a SQL Azure instance on a schedule basis.

In each table, I have around one millions records.

I need to schedule the table copy five times a day.

What are my options to copy this volume of data from SQL2012 to SQL Azure?

Considering the bandwidth limitations between on-prem data center and azure, Is this a feasible requirement?

Thank you,

Comment: After you have copied the initial 20 million rows from all the tables, how many rows would you copy during each one of the daily copies?

Comment: @Ola, I have to copy snapshots of the table. Delta extraction won't be an option.

Comment: In addition to trying the programmatic approach as suggested in the answer, I would give SSIS a shot. It would be quick to test since you're not dealing with figuring out what data that has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 
A) you have some .NET programming knowledge and B) the data should completely replace what is currently in the azure tables I would do the following.

Write some .NET code to read the data from the local db into a IDataReader, you don't mention about FK dependencies so you may have to take this into account.

Use [SQLBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) to insert the data into holding tables in azure such as
_myrealtablename. We use it we this in entity Framework [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/)

then when the data is uploaded, rename the tables within a transaction so the new tables have replaced the previous.

We see performance of ~100000 rows per second uploading in this manner on fairly wide tables. A few caveats would be how much data is changing, as timestamps and just updating changed and new entities may be easy.

If you wanted something more rudimentary you could use BCP to export and import the data

Answer (score 0):

Check out transactional replication: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db/.

Mihaela